# API to control Linux daemon

Tags: c++, linux

What I need is the possibility to control a Linux daemon though some sort of API, for example check if a certain daemon is running, start/stop/restart it, etc.

Is there any Linux library that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [D-Bus](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html) or [SNMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol). However, most daemons just write their PID to some file under `/var/run/` and accept the `SIGTERM` signal to stop, and the `SIGHUP` signal to reload their configuration files (usually under `/etc/`).

Notice that if you adopt the usual convention that your daemon program `mydprog` is writing its pid in `/var/run/mydprog.pid` some other program could read that pid there and check, using [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) with a 0 signal, that the daemon process is running. You might also access to some pseudo-files under `/proc/1234/` (where 1234 is the daemon's pid), notably `/proc/1234/status`, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more.

You can also design your daemon so that it answers, e.g. using some [JSONRPC](http://jsonrpc.org/) protocol on some [unix(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) or [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) socket, to some queries by giving status information. You might consider using some [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol thru some HTTP server library like [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/), or any other message passing or remote procedure call protocol.

Answer (score 0):

short answer is no.
Some daemons might have an api but that will be specific for that daemon.
You can run `/etc/init.d/<daemon_name> start|stop|status` to start stop or get the status most daemons

Comment: I hoped there would be some better way then using system("..."). So no Linux generic API?

Comment: You could use POSIX signals to stop a daemon, but that is the nearist ting to an daemon control API I can think off.